# How to remove a nested array element in Redux Reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

been banging my head against this for hours.

I am trying to remove a nested elment of an array in an object. It must be done immutably within a reducer, which is making it tricky.

Here is the object:

```
questions {
    0:
    answers: [{…}]
    createdAt: "2021-04-28T01:37:21.017Z"
    creator: "607f6ab0ee09c"
    likes: []
    name: "Firstname Lastname"
}
```

I want to remove just 1 element of the answers array. The problem is I don't know the exact element (of questions) until I search by 'creator' code, and then I can delete the answers element by key #.

I tried using map and filter, but with 3 layers deep that logic just never worked out. I'm also open to using Immutable-js.

thanks so much, quite a baffling issue for what seems like a simple thing to do.

EDIT:
I realized I can determine the key of the top level questions object in the action creator and send it over to the reducer.
So all I need to know how to do is remove an element of an array in an object, nested in another object.

thanks for any help!

Comment: "I tried using map and filter, but with 3 layers deep that logic just never worked out." Can you share the code?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan unfortunately I delete it as it wasn't working in any way shape or form how I intended.

Comment: How does you answer object look like in answers array

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri
{
Creator: 3282421
Likes: []
Body: "some message"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of clone your `questions` object by using `...` ES6 operator

`const clonedQuestion = {...questions}`

Now for removing element from answers array

```
const indexOfElementToRemove = clonedQuestion.answers.findIndex(element => element.creator === clonedQuestion.creator);
if(indexOfElementToRemove >= 0) {
  clonedQuestion.answers.splice(indexOfElementToRemove, 1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up needing to make clonedQuestion an array, not an object, and I also used a for loop instead of findIndex due to not being supported on IE, but the cloning of the state really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You might also take a look at the official redux toolkit, which would allow you to just use mutating logic like this in their `createReducer`- or `createSlice`- created reducers:

```js
delete state.questions.answers[5]
```

See this tutorial page that gives a short overview over what we consider as "modern redux": https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

If that is not something you want to do right now (keep in mind though, that modern redux and legacy redux can be mixed in an application), look into `immer` instead of `immutable` since `immutable` is essentially dead at this point and `immer` has a much better developer experience.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. This is one of the things I love and hate most about React. Always seems like there some great new thing to learn. For now I went with Priyank's suggestion below because it was plain JS, but I will study this in the future. Thank you.